# SQL "Distinct" and Group By Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

searching around this site but does not see any similar and helping thread.

Example: I have a data as below

```
Col1       Col2
aaaa       1111
aaaa       2222
bbbb       4444
bbbb       3333
```

How can I query to have a table like below ?

```
Col1       Col2
aaaa       1111
           2222
bbbb       4444
           3333
```

My current query to test this purpose

```
SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM msaEPGerror 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Col1,Col2
```

Tried using distinct and group by, but it still showing the other data as well. Yeah my db contained over hundred thousand of lines.
Is it possible ? I'm just trying my luck since previously I design thing using Report Builder, but now trying to migrate it to SQL.

Thanks

Comment: Explain your expected result more. there are NULLs in Col1? where do you expect the NULLs, because Col2 does not seem to be sorted.

Comment: SQL can't have the same display as in report builder, where cells are merged.

Comment: Try this in application layer

Comment: hi @EmilHolub, thanks for your response, there no null values in col1..my data contain many column actlly, but i want to select only 2 column and filter base on 1 column.

Comment: Hi @qxg, i think you answer my question, so does it mean impossible for me to merge col1 data ?

Comment: When displaying data from a database there are usually two parts: the DBMS to contain and give you the data, and a GUI to show it. By using ReportBuilder you should have these two, or are you saying that you didn't use SQL in ReportBuilder to access data from a DBMS? So you cannot really migrate *from* ReportBuilder *to* SQL. You could replace ReportBuilder by an app you write yourself, but it would still be the two components DBMS and GUI. So it seems what you are trying to do, doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You solved my problem already, I able to filter out the data. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using order by on col2 below query will work:

```
select case rank when 1 then col1 else '' end as col1, col2 
from (select col1,col2,
      rank() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as rank 
     from table1) tab;
```

Comment: The problem is the expected query result is not ordered by col2 - you can see that for "aaaa" there is "1111" as value but for bbbb there is "4444" not "3333"

Comment: Hi @Gaurav thanks for your help, i use exactly your query, the result still showing duplicate same data in column1...
To be exact, col1 is date, col2 is people.. I need to know who is working today, let say 10people, i need it to display only one date (which is today) and list 10people, but my query still showing 10same date and 10people, is it possible ?

Comment: @Sap1, maybe your dates are showing time component too, due to which they are being treated as distinct values in partition clause. Try partition by trunc(col1) order by col2.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following query and it'll return a single value for a specific column:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.id = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.id FROM Table t2
WHERE t2.Col1 = t.Col1
GROUP BY t2.Col1) THEN t.Col1
ELSE
''
END AS Col1, t.Col2
FROM Table t
```

I guess, the table has a primary key.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: You don't want to use `GROUP BY`, because this is to aggregate your data, such as to have one result row only per col1.

Then you don't want to use `DISTINCT` either, because that eliminates duplicate rows. Your table doesn't contain duplicate rows.

What you really want to do is suppress repeated values when displaying your data. You have to choices here: Either do this in your GUI (in a programm you write or in a report engine), which would would be the most common way to do this. Or use SQL to look into the previous record. The function to do this is `LAG`.

```
select
  col1,
  case when t.col1 = lag(t.col1) over (order by t.col1, t.col2) then null else col1 end
   as col2
from table1 t
order by t.col1, t.col2;
```

Comment: your answer and explanation was superb, LAG function really get me to what i'm looking for...yeah I know i should apply this to report engine, but seem you have made it clearer and I think i can achieve my point with this...thanks ! thanks all for helping ! :)